# Printing an entire list, instead of one line

Tags: string, split, extract, cifs

I am having trouble writing the entire list into an outfile. Here is the code:

```
with open(infline, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        if "ATOM" in l :
            split = l.split()
            if split[-1] == "1":
                print(split)
                #print(type(split))

            with open( newFile,"w") as f:
                f.write("Model Number One" + "\n")
                f.write(str(split))
```

When I use `print(split)` it allows me to see the entire list (image below):

```
with open(infile, "r") as f:

    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines: 
        if "ATOM" in l : 
            split = l.split()
            if split[-1] == "1":
                #print(split)
                print(type(split))
            
            with open( newFile,"w") as f: 
                f.write("Model Number One" + "\n")
                for i in range(len(split)):
                    f.write(str(split))
```

[image: Image of entire list]

However, when I try to use `f.write(split)` I get an error because the function can only take a `str` not a list. So, I used `f.write(str(split))` and it worked. The only issue now is that it only writes the last item in the list, not the whole list.

[image: image of the output for f.write (str(split))]

Comment: Please avoid posting images of code

Comment: Why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

The function `print` is slightly more permissible than the method `f.write`, in the sense that it can accept `lists` and various types of objects as input. `f.write` is usually called by passing pre-formatted strings, as you noticed.

I think the issue with the code is that the `write` routine is nested inside the code. This causes Python to erase any contents stored inside `newFile`, and write only the last line read `(l)`.

The problem can be easily fixed by changing the `open` call to `open( newFile,"a")`. The flag `"a"` tells Python to append the new contents to the existing file `newFile` (without erasing information). If `newFile` does not exist yet, Python will automatically create it.

Comment: It worked! The only issue now is that doesn't end. It keeps repeating the last line without ever stopping. The code should stop at line 501, but it continues to line 20,583

Comment: I guess the issue is that the last 2 lines of code repeat the entire `split` sentence for every element in `split`. You could try replacing the last 2 lines of code by just `f.write(str(split)+'\n')`